# Xcode c/c++ undefined symbols

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, extern

I have a .cpp file which I declare a function

```
#ifndef MyFile_hpp
#define MyFile_hpp

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void runCode();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

This works fine. I can call this function within my Objc. In my implementation I have an extern void that it will not let me call. It's giving the undefined symbols. I need this to build as is, the extern will be declared in a different file upon compiling. Having the extern, should this compiler just trust me and let me build?

```
#include "MyFile.h"

extern int runMe();

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void runCode() {
   runMe();
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
 #endif
```

Comment: Is the first shown code a .cpp file (as stated in the question body), a header named "MyFile.hpp" (as implied by the reinclusion guard) or a header named "MyFile.h" (the name used in the include line) ?

Comment: The first file named MyFile.h and second file is named MyFile.cpp

Comment: Can you show the definition of the function `runMe();`? I don't see it in the quoted code. I feel with the compiler/linker.

Comment: Is the shown code compiled by a C++ compiler or a C compiler? Is the extern compiled by C++ compiler or a C compiler?

Comment: What happens if you move the declaration of  `runMe()` into the extern "C"?

Comment: The runMe is not declared anywhere yet. It will be declared inside of a .c file. It is compiled by Xcode

Comment: It still fails if declared inside of the extern "C"

Comment: It is declared in the second non-empty line of the second code quote, by giving its prototype, with or without `extern` does not matter. If it "will be" defined after the linker attempts to link your code, then it is not yet at linking.

Comment: So when compiling the compiler needs to be able to find that function somewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169962/discussion-between-mkane-and-yunnosch).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing is probably correct.

The compiler doesn't just *trust you*. A C++ function is declared to the linker using additional characters, or "decorations" that define the full detail of the cclass it is a member of and all its arguments. A C function has none of that, just the raw name, so it is easy for the linker to tell the difference.

Comment: Calling the extern in .cpp gives this Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

Comment: What symbol does it say is undefined?

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "runMe()", referenced from:
      _runCode in MyFile.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: So you have to write your c++ function runMe in another .cpp file?

Comment: I will write that function runMe in a C file that hasn't been created yet

Comment: So surprise, you are being told it is undefined. Please define it :-)
You wrote the extern for runMe outside extern "C" {}, which tells the c++ compiler it is a c++ function, so you will need to write a c++ function, or move the extern..